# Multiple templates in Joomla, parent assets folder

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-template

I'm fairly new to Joomla, altough I've build a lot of Wordpress sites. Now, I have a project where I have four sections, like: Homepage - Branches - Products - Partners. They all have a fairly similar but still different layout.

In Wordpress I can make pages like index.php, branches.php etc using custom post types, while still using the same css and js assets.

How can I accomplish this in Joomla? My idea was to make a head template where all the assets are stored. Then I would make three other templates for the other three sections, importing all the assets. Is that even possible? Or is there an other/better solution?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your templates' `index.php` you can just reference the common assets:

```
<head>
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>templates/common/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>templates/this_template/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Then, using [Template styles](http://docs.joomla.org/Template_style), you can assign the templates to menu items.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for template overrides and yes you can reuse the assets like css, js etc in your Joomla template.